# What's the best way to terminate consumer/producer threads waiting on blocking data structures that are empty/full in C?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, producer-consumer, thread-synchronization

Let's say I have some consumer threads cycling reading elements infinitely from a blocking queue, and some producer threads that will produce a certain amount of elements on the same queue and then return. The consumers don't know how many elements will be inserted, that's why they keep cycling. After all the elements are produced and consumed, the consumer threads will get stuck waiting for more.

My goal is to make the consumers terminate in this scenario writing a "good" code to do so.

One possible solution in Java (that I don't think is easy/worth it to implement in C, correct me if I'm mistaken)
that looks good and "well abstracted" is to use Thread.interrupt() and exceptions in the following way, with 1 consumer and 1 producer in this example:

(haven't used java in a long time, sorry if there are mistakes, especially on generics)

```
public class Consume implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<T> queue;

    public Consume(BlockingQueue<T> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                T elem;
                elem = queue.take(); //Blocking
                //Do something with the element
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            //Do nothing and quit 
        }
    }
}

public class Produce implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<T> queue;

    public Produce(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        //Insert a random number of element in the queue,  and then quit
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(capacity);
    Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consume(queue));
    Thread producer = new Thread(new Produce(queue));

    consumer.start();
    producer.start();
    producer.join();
    consumer.interrupt();

    return 0;
}
```

This looks good enough to me because to terminate them I only need to use the same function (Thread.interrupt) for every type of data structure and without the need to access the internal implementation of the data structures.

In C, using pthreads, I could implement a solution with `pthread_cond_signal` / `*_broadcast` and the setting of some flag, but I would need to access the internal implementation of the data structure.

Is there a better way in general to face this problem? If not, can I implement something similar to the Java solution in C?

I found out that on MacOS a system signal received by a thread waiting with `pthread_cond_wait` will cause the function to return. I started writing a solution similar to the Java one based on this mechanism only to find out that `pthread_cond_wait` doesn't return on Linux, and I need my code to work on both OSes.

Comment: Depending on language, OS and thread API, it may or may not be possible to wait for multiple things at once. In that case it is appropriate to wait for "resource x" as well as waiting for a "time to close down the thread" event, both at once. Abruptly killing a thead with some "terminate thread" function is rarely ever the correct solution.

Comment: That Java code is not as reliable as you may think.  Depending on timing, that use of `Thread.interrupt()` might not actually cause the consumer to terminate.  It could just cause the thread's `interrupted` status to be set, but nothing there checks for that.

Comment: Related: [What happens on Linux (and MacOS) if a process receives a signal while waiting on pthread_cond_wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76956112/2402272)

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right about the code not working, and I'm not managing to find a way to fix it. Don't know if it's possible and how to check Thread.interrupted() to be sure to always catch either the flag or the exception. Yes, the other question is mine.

Comment: Even if I check Thread.interrupted() right before queue.take() the interrupt could arrive between the two calls, not being seen by Thread.interrupted() and not causing the exception to be thrown

Comment: BlockingQueue's take() method does take interrupting into account. But I would solve it a different way. You could produce some special, signal value that indicates to the consumer that there will be no more data so it can shut down cleanly. For example, instead of `T`, have a queue of `Optional<T>`, and send it `Optional.empty()` to tell it it's time to stop.

Comment: @DavidConrad  You mean I should send a special value on the queue itself? If yes, the problem is in the program I'm working on I both need to be able to tell the consumers to terminate after reading the last elements on the queue (when no more will be inserted), possible to do in the way you suggested, and to stop reading as soon as possible when a certain condition arises,  ignoring elements left on the queue, which can't be done that way.

Comment: Ah, my suggestion won't work then for the latter case.

Comment: How about a `PriorityQueue` of objects that have an integer priority, the data, and a flag to indicate whether to stop. The producer could produce items with sequential priorities of 1, 2, 3, etc. and when it wants the consumer to stop, produce one with priority -1 and the flag set to true?

Comment: That would work! Edit: Oh I see you posted a full answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best way to terminate consumer/producer threads waiting on blocking data structures that are empty/full in C?

The best way is to use (possibly write) a data structure and associated functions that provide explicitly for external interruption.  The usual idiom for this sort of thing relies on the Swiss army knife of thread synchronization: the condition variable.  That applies in both C and Java, although Java makes that more accessible by endowing *every* Object with built-in mutex and CV functionality.<sup>*</sup>  Such a data structure uses no blocking functions other than mutex and CV waits, and interruption revolves around broadcasting to that CV.

To understand how that would work you must first understand [how properly to use CVs to implement blocking data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579987/2402272) in general.  Note in particular that the correct idiom for retrieving data from such a data structure follows these steps:

**Retrieve datum**

1. Lock the data structure
2. Check whether a datum is available for retrieval
3. If not:

   3.1. wait upon a CV designated for the purpose

   3.2. upon return from the wait, loop back to (2)
4. Remove the datum
5. Unlock the data structure

The corresponding procedure for depositing data in that structure follows these steps:

**Deposit datum**

1. Lock the data structure
2. Add the datum
3. Unlock the data structure
4. signal or broadcast to the CV (this step and the previous can be performed in either order)

Notes:

- **The retrieval procedure blocks only on a CV wait**, and then only if no data are initially available for retrieval.
- **The retrieval procedure loops** after waiting. This is essential because spurious wakeups are possible (in both C and Java), and it provides natural flexibility with respect to whether the CV is signaled or broadcast to.
- A CV wait releases the associated lock (but only that one) before blocking, then reacquires it before returning.

Now consider step (2) in the retrieval procedure.  It involves performing a test before every possible wait, and control returns there after every wait for a determination of whether a new wait should be performed.  The simple scheme above shows making that determination based only on whether any data are available, but you can insert any additional *conditions* you like there. The combined condition tested here is the namesake for which "condition variables" are named.

In particular, you can add a test for whether a termination flag has been set.  With that modification in place, the termination procedure looks a lot like the data deposition procedure.  For example:

**Terminate**

1. Lock the data structure
2. Set a termination flag
3. Unlock the data structure
4. Broadcast to the CV (this step and the previous can be performed in either order)

In this case, however, it is essential to broadcast to the CV rather than signaling it if there is any possibility that more than one thread is waiting.

---

<sup>*</sup> Java also added higher-level abstractions for locks and CVs, and a bunch of standard data structures providing for safe concurrent use.  To my knowledge, however, none of the standard library classes provide directly for the kind of explicit termination request required here.

Comment: So this kind interruption is best to be "coded inside" data structures? I saw java never did this and I assumed there was a more general and simple way to do so

Comment: Yes, @Ernaldo, that such an interruption is best implemented directly by your data structure / its associated functions is precisely my answer.  Lots of *Java code* does exactly the kind of thing I describe.  The standard library's concurrent data structures do not, but that is neither here nor there.

Comment: I don't know why I asked again what you stated in the first 2 lines of your answer. Thank you for the detailed response, I will apply this to my code.

Comment: One more thing, what's usually left of the data structure after the termination is done? Should I simply destroy it,  make it "usable" again, or leave it unusable (meaning its functions now have unspecified behaviour) and let the user explicitly destroy it with the appropriate function?

Comment: That's up to you, @Ernaldo.  It is perhaps safest to use a one & done approach, such that once the termination flag is raised, it cannot be lowered.  The logic is simpler, and there are fewer openings for misuse.  You could nevertheless implement some kind of reset feature, but in addition to increasing the complexity and misuse potential, I think you would find that that feature was rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach in Java. Use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and a wrapper type that has an integer priority, the payload, and a flag.

```
record Prioritized<T>(int priority, T value, boolean stop)
        implements Comparable<Prioritized<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Prioritized<T> that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.priority, that.priority);
    }
}
```

Depending on the version of Java this could be written as a `class` instead of a `record`.

Create a `PriorityBlockingQueue<Prioritized<Data>>` to pass values of some type `Data` between the producer and the consumer. In the producer, produce values with sequential priorities (or even a constant, positive priority):

```
int serialNumber = 1;
queue.put(new Prioritized<>(serialNumber++, data, false));
```

When it's time to stop the consumer, add an entry with priority -1 and the stop flag set to true. The data doesn't matter since the consumer will check the flag before looking at the data.

```
queue.put(new Prioritized<>(-1, null, true));
```

In the consumer, take items from the queue, stopping if the flag is set:

```
while (true) {
    Prioritized<Data> item = queue.take();
    if (item.stop()) {
        break;
    }
    process(item.value());
}
```

In C, use a heap implementation to replace Java's PriorityBlockingQueue (which is backed by a heap data structure) and a `struct` with similar members as Prioritized.

Comment: I don't remember much of threading in Java, are these containers thread-safe? Either way I don't see how some sort of struct data type would solve this in C. Because such a data type would have to be protected against race conditions... And then you end up waiting for a semaphore instead of whatever you were previously waiting for. Essentially the problem is just moved to a different place.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, `PriorityQueue` is not thread-safe, it should be `PriorityBlockingQueue`. There is no race condition, since the data type is immutable. In C you would have to rely on const and the producer not modifying it once it created it. I suppose the producer would be `malloc`ing these and the consumer `free`ing them.

Comment: Although the question presents a Java example, its actual thrust is about how to implement similar behavior in C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a good point, but I don't see why essentially the same thing can't be done in C. A heap for the priority queue, a struct instead of a class, I think the main problem in C is the ownership of the objects since there's no garbage collector. The consumer would have to be responsible for freeing them.

Comment: You're right, @DavidConrad. The same thing certainly could be done in C.  However, if one has to prepare one's own concurrent queue anyway (as is probable in C) then it would be simpler and more straightforward to prepare one that has built-in support for the kind of termination the OP requires.

Comment: @JohnBollinger unlike your approach with a shared condition variable, what I am aiming for is essentially the [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) where nothing is shared and all communication is via message passing between the threads. Unfortunately, one thing does have to be shared, the queue for the messages, and that would require a mutex to ensure both are not modifying it at the same time. So maybe your approach is better in C.

Comment: @DavidConrad, for satisfactory operation, your approach requires not only a shared mutex equivalent, but also a shared CV equivalent.  A mutex alone is not adequate for making threads wait for data when none is already available.  `PriorityBlockingQueue` hides those from users, but both are still there.  With that said, if one already has a C analog of `PriorityBlockingQueue`, then your approach does provide a way to layer termination semantics on top.

Answer (score -1):

The Ada language provides a commonly used paradigm for this problem. Implementing this in C would require a significant effort.

Ada provides both synchronous communication between tasks (usually implemented as OS thread) and asynchronous communication between tasks.

Associated with the problem specified in this question the synchronous communication allows a task to synchronously message another task when to shut down.

The asynchronous communication deals with the use of a shared buffer as expected in a producer-consumer pattern.

The following code demonstrates use of both of these communication paths while implementing a producer-consumer pattern which supports P producers and C consumers where P > 0 and C > 0.

This example is implemented using an Ada package. The Ada package is implemented in two files. The first file is the package specification, declaring the public interface to the package. The package specification serves a similar purpose to a C header file. The second file is the package body containing the implementation of the software in the package.

```ada
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Producer-consumer with bounded buffer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
generic
   Capacity : Positive;
package Bounded_PC is
   task type Producer is
      entry set_id(Id : in Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Producer;

   task type Consumer is
      entry set_id(Id : in Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Consumer;

end Bounded_PC;
```

This is a generic package. The generic parameter is named Capacity. The Capacity parameter allows the programmer to customize the capacity of the buffer shared by the producer and consumer tasks.

Two task types are declared. The interface to the Producer task type is the same as the interface to the Consumer task type. Declaration of a task type allows the programmer to create 1 or more instances of each task type in the program using the package.

Each task type declares two task entries. The set_id entry allows the task to be assigned an Id number. The parameter for the set_id entry is an instance of the language-defined subtype Positive. Positive is an Integer (typically 32 bits) with a minimum value of 1. The Stop entry has no parameter. It behaves as a parameter-less event notification.

The implementation of this package is in the package body.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;     use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Bounded_PC is
   subtype Index_T is Positive range 1 .. Capacity;
   type Buf_Array is array (Index_T) of Integer;

   ------------
   -- Buffer --
   ------------

   protected Buffer is
      entry Write (Item : in Integer);
      entry Read (Item : out Integer);
      function Is_Empty return Boolean;
   private
      Buf         : Buf_Array;
      Write_Index : Index_T := 1;
      Read_Index  : Index_T := 1;
      Count       : Natural := 0;
   end Buffer;

   protected body Buffer is

      entry Write (Item : in Integer) when Count < Capacity is
      begin
         Buf (Write_Index) := Item;
         Write_Index       := (Write_Index mod Capacity) + 1;
         Count             := Count + 1;
      end Write;

      entry Read (Item : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Item       := Buf (Read_Index);
         Read_Index := (Read_Index mod Capacity) + 1;
         Count      := Count - 1;
      end Read;
      
      function Is_Empty return Boolean is
      begin
         return Count = 0;
      end Is_Empty;
      

   end Buffer;

   --------------
   -- Producer --
   --------------

   task body Producer is
      Value : Integer := 0;
      Me    : Positive;
   begin
      accept set_id (Id : in Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end set_id;

      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            Put_Line("Producer" & Me'Image & " is terminating.");
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Write (Value);
               Put_Line ("Producer" & Me'Image & " wrote" & Value'Image);
               Value := Value + 1;
            or
               delay 0.001;
               Put_Line ("Producer" & Me'Image & " is waiting ....");
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Producer;

   --------------
   -- Consumer --
   --------------

   task body Consumer is
      Value : Integer;
      Me    : Positive;
      Done  : Boolean := False;
   begin
      accept set_id (Id : in Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end set_id;

      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            Done := True;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Read (Value);
               Put_Line ("Consumer" & Me'Image & " read" & Value'Image);
            or
               delay 0.001;
               if Done and then Buffer.Is_Empty then
                  Put_Line("Consumer" & Me'Image & " terminating.");
                  exit;
               else
                  Put_Line ("Consumer" & Me'Image & " is waiting ....");
               end if;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Consumer;

end Bounded_PC;
```

The package specification only declared the publicly accessible components of the package. The fixed-length buffer shared by the producer tasks and the consumer tasks is not publicly accessible, but is accessible by the tasks themselves. It is therefore defined within the package body and not exposed outside the package body.

Ada allows the declaration of array types. Ada array types allow index values to start at any programmer-defined value and end at any other programmer-defined value of the same type. If the ending index value is less than the starting index value the array type is an array containing no elements.

A subtype of Positive (the same subtype as the generic parameter Capacity) is defined to be in the range of 1 through Capacity. That subtype is used to index the array type named Buf_Array. Each element of Buf_Array is an Integer.

The actual buffer is an Ada protected object. Ada protected objects are passive units of concurrency. They are shared by tasks, which are active units of concurrency. Three kinds of protected methods are allowed to be defined.

- Procedures are allowed to unconditionally read and write to the protected object. An exclusive read-write lock is implicitly managed when the procedure is executed.
- Entries are allowed to conditionally read and write to the protected object. An exclusive read-write lock is implicitly managed when the entry is executed. A task may only execute an entry when its boundary condition evaluates to TRUE. While the boundary condition evaluates to FALSE all tasks calling the entry are suspended in an implicitly managed entry queue.
- Functions are allowed to only read data from the protected object. Functions manage a shared read-only lock on the protected object. Multiple tasks may read data from the protected object simultaneously using a function. No procedure or entry may execute while the shared read-only lock is asserted.

This example only uses two protected entries and one protected function. The Write entry allows the calling task to add an element to the protected object. The Read entry allows the calling task to read an element from the protected object. The Is_Empty function allows a calling task to determine whether or not the protected object contains valid values.

Protected objects also have two parts; a specification and a body. The protected specification exposes the two entries which can be called and also defines the private data within the protected object. In this example you see an instance of the Buf_Array named Buf, a field named Writ_Index, a field named Read_Index and a field named Count. Buf is the where the shared data is stored. Write_Index is used by the Write entry to manage writing to the queue implemented on the Buf field. Read_Index is used by the Read entry to manage reading data from the queue implemented in Buf. Count keeps track of the number of elements currently holding valid data in the queue implemented by Buf.

The protected body contains the implementation of the Write and Read entries.

The Write entry has a single parameter passing an Integer into the entry when Count < Capacity. This means a task calling Write will be suspended in the Write entry queue as long as Count >= Capacity. The logic of the Write entry is executed by a calling task only when the boundary condition is TRUE. That logic is simple. The value passed in the parameter named Item is assigned to the element of Buf indexed by Write_Index. Write_Index is incremented using modular arithmetic so that the array is treated as a circular buffer. Count is incremented.

The Read entry has a single parameter passing an Integer out of the entry to the calling task when Count > 0. Tasks calling Read can only read a value from the protected object when the buffer is not empty. The logic of the Read entry assigns the parameter Item the value of Buf indexed by Read_Index. Read_Index is incremented using modular arithmetic so that the array is treated as a circular buffer. Count is decremented.

The Is_Empty function returns a Boolean value which is TRUE when Count equals 0 and FAlSE when Count does not equal 0. Count is an instance of the pre-defined subtype Natural which is an Integer with a minimum value of 0. Count can therefore not ever contain a value less than 0.

The task types are implemented in the task bodies. This is where the communication patterns occur that provide the answer to the question of how the consumer task(s) can work until they are commanded to stop.

The producer task first accepts its set_id entry. This is done synchronously. The producer task will suspend at the accept statement until another task calls its corresponding entry. Upon completion of the accept clause the task enters an infinite loop which is only terminated by accepting the Stop entry for the task.

The Stop entry is accepted within a select clause. Select clauses allow conditional acceptance of an entry. The producer task accepts its Stop entry only if another task is calling that entry. It another task is calling the Stop entry the Producer outputs a message stating it is terminating and then exits the loop. If no other task is calling that entry the producer task selectively calls the Buffer.Write entry. If Buffer is not full the boundary condition on Buffer.Write entry completes, the producer writes a message to standard output and increments Value. If Buffer is full the Producer task waits up to 0.001 seconds (1 millisecond) and then abandons the call to Buffer.Write, producing a message indicating the Producer is waiting. The loop is then repeated.

The Consumer task has a very similar behavior to the Producer task.

It accepts the set_id entry then enters an infinite loop checking whether or not the Stop entry has been called and then reading values from the Buffer protected object. When the Stop entry has been accepted the Consumer sets the Boolean variable Done to TRUE and continues iterating through the loop. The Consumer continues processing Buffer data elements until Done is TRUE and Buffer.Is_Empty returns TRUE. This allows the Consumer to finish processing all values written by Producer tasks and then terminate.

The Main procedure for this example follows:

```ada
with Bounded_PC;

procedure Main is
   package Int_Pck is new Bounded_PC (10);
   use Int_Pck;

   P1 : Producer;
   P2 : Producer;
   C1 : Consumer;
   C2 : Consumer;
begin
   P1.set_id (1);
   P2.set_id (2);
   C1.set_id (1);
   C2.set_id (2);
   delay 0.003;
   P1.Stop;
   P2.Stop;
   delay 0.01;
   C1.Stop;
   C2.Stop;
end Main;
```

The Main procedure creates an instance of the Bounded_PC package passing 10 to the Capacity generic parameter. This creates a fixed buffer of 10 elements for this example.

Main creates two instances of Producer named P1 and P2 followed by two instances of Consumer named C1 and C1. All four tasks begin executing immediately.

Following the "begin" reserved word the Main procedure calls the set_id entry for each task, delays (sleeps) for 0.003 seconds (3 milliseconds), calls the Stop entries for the two producer tasks, delays another 0.01 seconds (10 milliseconds) and calls the stop entry for the two consumers.

A typical output of this program is:

```text
Producer 1 wrote 0
Consumer 1 read 0
Consumer 1 read 1
Consumer 2 read 0
Producer 1 wrote 1
Producer 2 wrote 0
Consumer 1 read 2
Producer 2 wrote 1
Consumer 2 read 1
Producer 1 wrote 2
Consumer 1 read 2
Producer 2 wrote 2
Consumer 2 read 3
Producer 1 wrote 3
Consumer 1 read 3
Producer 2 wrote 3
Consumer 2 read 4
Producer 1 wrote 4
Consumer 1 read 4
Consumer 2 read 5
Producer 1 wrote 5
Producer 2 wrote 4
Consumer 1 read 6
Producer 1 wrote 6
Producer 2 wrote 5
Consumer 2 read 5
Producer 2 wrote 6
Consumer 2 read 6
Consumer 2 read 7
Producer 2 wrote 7
Producer 1 wrote 7
Consumer 2 read 8
Producer 2 wrote 8
Producer 2 wrote 9
Producer 2 wrote 10
Consumer 2 read 8
Consumer 1 read 7
Producer 1 wrote 8
Consumer 1 read 10
Producer 2 wrote 11
Consumer 2 read 9
Consumer 2 read 9
Consumer 2 read 12
Producer 2 wrote 12
Consumer 1 read 11
Producer 1 wrote 9
Producer 2 wrote 13
Consumer 1 read 10
Producer 2 wrote 14
Consumer 2 read 13
Consumer 1 read 14
Consumer 2 read 15
Producer 2 wrote 15
Producer 1 wrote 10
Consumer 1 read 16
Producer 1 wrote 11
Producer 2 wrote 16
Consumer 2 read 11
Producer 2 wrote 17
Consumer 2 read 17
Producer 2 wrote 18
Consumer 2 read 18
Producer 2 wrote 19
Consumer 2 read 19
Producer 2 wrote 20
Producer 2 wrote 21
Consumer 2 read 20
Producer 2 wrote 22
Consumer 2 read 21
Producer 2 wrote 23
Consumer 2 read 22
Producer 2 wrote 24
Producer 2 wrote 25
Producer 1 wrote 12
Producer 2 wrote 26
Consumer 2 read 23
Producer 2 wrote 27
Consumer 2 read 24
Producer 2 wrote 28
Consumer 2 read 25
Producer 2 wrote 29
Consumer 2 read 26
Producer 2 wrote 30
Consumer 2 read 13
Producer 2 wrote 31
Consumer 2 read 27
Producer 2 wrote 32
Consumer 2 read 28
Producer 2 wrote 33
Consumer 2 read 29
Producer 2 wrote 34
Producer 2 wrote 35
Consumer 2 read 30
Producer 2 wrote 36
Consumer 2 read 31
Producer 2 wrote 37
Consumer 2 read 32
Producer 2 wrote 38
Consumer 2 read 33
Consumer 2 read 34
Producer 2 wrote 39
Consumer 2 read 35
Producer 2 wrote 40
Producer 1 wrote 13
Producer 2 wrote 41
Consumer 1 read 12
Producer 1 wrote 14
Producer 2 wrote 42
Consumer 1 read 37
Producer 1 wrote 15
Producer 1 wrote 16
Producer 1 wrote 17
Producer 1 wrote 18
Consumer 1 read 38
Producer 2 wrote 43
Consumer 2 read 36
Producer 1 wrote 19
Consumer 2 read 40
Producer 2 wrote 44
Consumer 2 read 41
Producer 1 wrote 20
Consumer 2 read 14
Consumer 1 read 39
Consumer 2 read 42
Consumer 1 read 15
Consumer 2 read 43
Consumer 1 read 16
Consumer 2 read 17
Consumer 1 read 18
Consumer 2 read 19
Consumer 2 read 44
Consumer 1 read 20
Producer 2 wrote 45
Consumer 1 read 21
Consumer 2 read 45
Consumer 1 read 46
Producer 2 wrote 46
Producer 1 wrote 21
Producer 2 wrote 47
Producer 1 wrote 22
Producer 2 wrote 48
Producer 2 wrote 49
Consumer 1 read 22
Producer 2 wrote 50
Producer 2 wrote 51
Producer 2 wrote 52
Producer 2 wrote 53
Producer 2 wrote 54
Producer 2 wrote 55
Producer 2 wrote 56
Consumer 1 read 48
Consumer 1 read 23
Producer 2 wrote 57
Producer 2 wrote 58
Producer 2 wrote 59
Producer 1 wrote 23
Consumer 1 read 49
Consumer 2 read 47
Consumer 1 read 50
Consumer 1 read 52
Consumer 1 read 53
Consumer 1 read 54
Consumer 1 read 55
Consumer 1 read 56
Consumer 1 read 57
Producer 1 wrote 24
Consumer 1 read 58
Producer 1 wrote 25
Consumer 2 read 51
Producer 2 wrote 60
Consumer 2 read 60
Producer 2 wrote 61
Consumer 2 read 24
Producer 1 wrote 26
Consumer 2 read 25
Producer 2 wrote 62
Consumer 2 read 26
Consumer 2 read 61
Consumer 2 read 62
Consumer 2 read 27
Consumer 2 read 63
Producer 2 wrote 63
Producer 2 wrote 64
Producer 2 wrote 65
Producer 2 wrote 66
Producer 2 wrote 67
Producer 2 wrote 68
Consumer 2 read 64
Producer 1 wrote 27
Producer 2 wrote 69
Producer 1 wrote 28
Producer 2 wrote 70
Producer 2 wrote 71
Producer 2 wrote 72
Producer 2 wrote 73
Producer 1 wrote 29
Consumer 2 read 65
Consumer 1 read 59
Consumer 2 read 66
Consumer 1 read 67
Producer 1 wrote 30
Consumer 2 read 68
Producer 2 wrote 74
Consumer 2 read 28
Consumer 2 read 70
Consumer 2 read 29
Consumer 2 read 71
Consumer 2 read 72
Consumer 2 read 73
Consumer 2 read 74
Consumer 2 read 30
Consumer 2 read 31
Consumer 2 read 75
Producer 1 wrote 31
Producer 2 wrote 75
Producer 1 is terminating.
Producer 2 wrote 76
Producer 2 wrote 77
Consumer 1 read 69
Producer 2 wrote 78
Consumer 2 read 76
Producer 2 is terminating.
Consumer 1 read 77
Consumer 2 read 78
Consumer 1 is waiting ....
Consumer 2 is waiting ....
Consumer 2 is waiting ....
Consumer 1 is waiting ....
Consumer 2 is waiting ....
Consumer 1 terminating.
Consumer 2 terminating.
```